# Kinetic energy of electron in Quantum well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, degrees-of-freedom

I heard that electrons in bulk semiconductor have 3 degree of freedom so they have 3 dimensional kinetic energy component, but Whenever an electron from bulk material captured by a quantum well (where it has only 2 degree of freedom) that electron's 3rd dimensional kinetic energy component vanishes., But where that goes, is it added to the other 2 dimensions?